# Solving integral with exponential function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I’m interested in solving the integral
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} {\frac{2}{3x^{4/3}} \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}} \exp \left( \frac{-\lambda (x^{2/3}-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2 x^{2/3}}  \right) dx}
$$
for $\mu>0, \lambda>0$.
WolframAlpha does not give me a solution but maybe you know some tricks how to simplify the integral. Thanks!

Comment: have you proved that your integral does converge on the given interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you some steps:

First, do the change of variables $x=u^{3/2}$. That will turn your integral into
$$
I=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{u^{3/2}}\exp\biggl(-\frac{\lambda(u-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2u}\biggr)\,du.
$$
Next, performing $u\mapsto \mu^2/u$, you will find that
$$
I=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\mu u^{1/2}}\exp\biggl(-\frac{\lambda(u-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2u}\biggr)\,du.
$$
Adding these, you get
$$
2I=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\mu+u}{\mu u^{3/2}}\exp\biggl(-\frac{\lambda(u-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2u}\biggr)\,du.
$$
Now, you are lucky, since
$$
\frac{d}{du}\frac{2(u-\mu)}{\mu\sqrt{u}}=\frac{\mu+u}{\mu u^{3/2}}.
$$
Hence, set
$$
t=\frac{2(u-\mu)}{\mu\sqrt{u}}.
$$
You find that
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\biggl(-\frac{\lambda t^2}{8}\biggr)\,du.
$$
We are back in our (mine!) comfort zone with the gaussians, and since
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi}
$$
we use scaling to conclude that

> $$I=1.$$

Comment: +1. Pretty fine. It'll be nice the OP 'remove' all of the annoying factors before he/she sets the question !!!.

Comment: Nice solution!! Thanks a lot! And next time I'll remove the factors.