# Closed form for integrals of an exponential with rational function argument?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, improper-integrals, rational-functions

I am trying to find the closed form for the following integral:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a^2(x-b)^2+\frac{c}{1+x^2}}\ {\rm d}x$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, and $a\ge0$. I know that the integral is  gaussian at $c=0$, but I am trying to find it for $c>0$.

Edit:
This integral appeared in the calculation of the average interaction of particles that follows Gaussian distribution $e^{-a^2(x-b)^2}$, where $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}$ and $b=\mu$, with a field $e^{\frac{c}{1+x^2}}$, where "$c$" controls the strength and width of the field. This integral is convergent.
I looked through integrals in [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780123849335/table-of-integrals-series-and-products), but I could not find an answer. Also i look through these solutions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435849/an-improper-integral-of-an-exponential-with-rational-fraction-argument), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187777/compute-integral-of-exponential-with-polynomial-division-in-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295315/solving-integral-with-exponential-function?rq=1), but it does not help here.

My idea of solution was by expanding the field function using Taylor expansion, which leads to the following integral:
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{c^n}{n!(1+x^2)^n}e^{-a^2(x-b)^2}\ {\rm d}x$$
the resultant integral is hard to solve.

Comment: Please add relevant context (source, motivation, your background and ideas for solution etc). As of now it runs the risk of getting closed soon.

Comment: Updated for easier calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being myself a quantum mechanicist, I faced a quite similar problem and my approached was presented in a conference almost fifty years ago.

The idea is the same as your (expand as a series). The problem is that
$$J= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-a^2(x-b)^2}}{(1+x^2)^n}\,  dx$$ does not seem to show solution.

What I proposed was to expand now the integrand as
$$\frac{e^{-a^2(x-b)^2}}{(1+x^2)^n}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-a^2x^2}}{(1+x^2)^n} d_m\,b^m$$ where
$$d_0=e^{-a^2 x^2}\qquad d_1=2 a^2 x e^{-a^2 x^2}\quad \quad d_m=\frac 2 m a^2(x\, d_{m-1}-d_{m-2})$$

The $d_m$ being polynomials of degree $m$ in $x$, what is required is to compute only the even terms
$$K_{2p}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-a^2x^2}}{(1+x^2)^n}x^{2p}\,  dx$$  which are
$$K_{2p}=a^{(2 n-2 p-1)}\,\Gamma \left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)\, 
   U\left(n,n-p+\frac{1}{2},a^2\right)$$  where $U(.)$ is Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind (see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)).

The calculations would be easy since (see [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.3))
$$0=a^2 (n+1) \,U\left(n+2,n-p+\frac{5}{2},a^2\right)+$$ $$\left(a^2-n+p-\frac{1}{2}\right)\, U\left(n+1,n-p+\frac{3}{2},a^2\right)-U\left(n,n-p+\frac{1}{2},a^2\right)$$with
$$U\left(1,1-p+\frac{1}{2},a^2\right)=e^{a^2} E_{p+\frac{1}{2}}\left(a^2\right)$$
$$U\left(2,2-p+\frac{1}{2},a^2\right)=\frac{e^{a^2} \left(2 a^2+2 p-1\right) E_{p-\frac{1}{2}}\left(a^2\right)-2}{2 p-1}$$  where appears the exponential integral function.

Comment: It is an intersting solution!!!